# Google assistant to run python script

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I have installed the google assistant SDK on a raspberry pi 3 and have so far managed to get Spotify working, and managed to get IFTTT to run for lights. What I really want to know is whether it is possible to have google assistant run and interact with python scripts on the pi. By which I mean I have a script called sound_the_alarm.py which pulls news from different sources, gives updates on bitcoin etc, and then plays a random song from my library, and turns on a light via gpio. I would like to be able to say “ok google sound the alarm at 7:00 tomorrow and have it update the crib tab with an instance of the alarm. Is this possible? I have found nothing online suggesting so! 
Thanks
Will

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not directly, as I know.

I use IFTTT for that (check on youtube how easy it is).

The easiest way is to have public IP with your raspberry, but it is dangerous (see below for solution).

1. Log into ifttt.com and make an applet: Google Assistant Command to Webhook. It is a piece of cake. You will learn it in minutes (use youtube for tutorial).
2. You type as a webhook public IP of your raspberry with a link to PHP app.
3. Your PHP app fetches the info about command from Google Assistant and exec("Your command here");

Additional info:

1. It is probably possible to make fetching app in Python instead of PHP, but I am not a Python programmer, so I cannot help with it. I use PHP for that.
2. It is MUUUCH SAFER to make additional "Gate Server". Take the cheapest hosting provider. Make an APP on this server (probably in PHP :P). Your IFTTT sends a request to the Gate (instead of raspberry directly). And your raspberry pi contacts the gate checking if there are no any orders for it. If there is any, it follows the order. Because of that nobody knows your raspberry IP address. You can hide it behind the router so it is more less safe.

I hope my solution is understandable :).

K.